# Make tasktracker wait after a failure

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am running a M/R job on an Hadoop cluster and encounter some failures in a Tasktracker once in a while. I know the nature of these failure and know that when it occurs in a task, this Tasktracker won't be able to work properly during at least two minutes.

My question is simple: is it possible to ask a Tasktracker to "sleep", i.e. not accept any new task, during a few minutes after it fails on a task?

Thanks in advance,

Adrien

Comment: Maybe you can adjust the heartbeat frequency? I assume that if the time between heartbeats is higher than 2 minutes the jobtracker won't sent a new task to the tasktracker? It's just an idea, not sure if this is the way it works.
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml
The link above contains a number of heartbeat properties you can set.

Comment: `mapreduce.tasktracker.tasks.sleeptimebeforesigkill` 
_The time, in milliseconds, the tasktracker waits for sending a SIGKILL to a task, after it has been sent a SIGTERM. This is currently not used on WINDOWS where tasks are just sent a SIGTERM._  This could be interesting as well?

Comment: Thanks irW. I don't see what parameter to use for a two minute heartbeat at the tasktracker level, and unfortunately I don't think it would work anyways. The second parameter seems to be triggered only when the whole tasktracker is stopped, not the individual tasks (I did a a test and it didn't work).

Comment: Maybe you could give more details about the task failure, I think your question is a little too general, in its current form it is possible that there is no solution to your problem, but if you can communicate more details about the task failure maybe there are some tricks (I am definitely no expert but your question may catch the attention of more experienced hadoop people here)